# Recent College grad in need of car

Tags: car, college, auto-leasing

I am a recent college grad with a salary around 48k/yr at a very stable job.

When I began college my father leased a 2013 Hyundai Sonata for me with a 208/monthly payment. My lease is about to be up in January and I need to find a new car.

I want to be completely independent and thus need a car, on my own. I don't need anything fancy, just something that can get me from point a to point b.

I have never purchased a car but most of my older friends always recommend that I buy a used car instead of taking a lease on car.

**Question**:
Should I try to lease a similar car and hope I can negotiate for the same Payments
OR
Buy a used car.

If the answer is it depends, then can some one provide what factors should I consider before I make a decision.

Comment: Can you edit and add country? What is the price for a similar used car? What are the terms of lease, i.e. payments for how long and do you have an option of buying back at end of lease? What about maintenance during lease period, is this with you or the company that has leased you the vehicle. Is there any mileage or any other restriction on the leased car?

Answer (score 3):

Buy a used car. Lease is almost never a good deal unless you are writing it off on taxes.

Comment: Not sure why anyone would down vote common sense, but in retaliation an up vote.